# Multiclass classification in Spark with Term Frequency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am quite new to Apache Spark and MLlib and trying to do my first multiclass-classification model. I stuck at some point... Here is my code:

```
val input = sc.textFile("cars2.csv").map(line => line.split(";").toSeq)
```

Creating Data Frame:

```
val sql = new SQLContext(sc)
val schema = StructType(List(StructField("Description", StringType), StructField("Brand", StringType), StructField("Fuel", StringType)))
val dataframe = sql.createDataFrame(input.map(row => Row(row(0), row(1), row(2))), schema)
```

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
+-----------------+----------+------+
|      Description|     Brand|  Fuel|
+-----------------+----------+------+
|  giulietta 1.4TB|alfa romeo|PETROL|
|               4c|alfa romeo|PETROL|
| giulietta 2.0JTD|alfa romeo|DIESEL|
|   Mito 1.4 Tjet |alfa romeo|PETROL|
|     a1 1.4  TFSI|      AUDI|PETROL|
|      a1 1.0 TFSI|      AUDi|PETROL|
|      a3 1.4 TFSI|      AUDI|PETROL|
|      a3 1.2 TFSI|      AUDI|PETROL|
|       a3 2.0 Tdi|      AUDI|DIESEL|
|       a3 1.6 TDi|      AUDI|DIESEL|
|        a3 1.8tsi|      AUDI|PETROL|
|             RS3 |      AUDI|PETROL|
|               S3|      AUDI|PETROL|
|        A4 2.0TDI|      AUDI|DIESEL|
|        A4 2.0TDI|      AUDI|DIESEL|
|      A4 1.4 tfsi|      AUDI|PETROL|
|       A4 2.0TFSI|      AUDI|PETROL|
|        A4 3.0TDI|      AUDI|DIESEL|
|          X5 3.0D|       BMW|DIESEL|
|             750I|       BMW|PETROL|
```

Then:

```
//Tokenize
val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("Description").setOutputCol("tokens")
val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(dataframe)

    //Creating term-frequency 
val htf = new HashingTF().setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("rawFeatures").setNumFeatures(500)
val tf = htf.transform(tokenized)

val idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features")


// Model & Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setMaxIter(20).setRegParam(0.01)

import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, idf, lr))
//Model
val model = pipeline.fit(dataframe)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "rawFeatures" does not exist.
```

I am trying to predict Brand and Fuel type by only reading Description.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Two small issues with your code:

1. `htf` variable isn't used, I assume it's missing from the pipeline? Since this is the `PipelineStage` creating the `rawFeatures` field required by the next stage, you get the `Field does not exist` error.
2. Even if we fix this - the last stage (LogisticRegression) will fail because it requires a `label` field with type `DoubleType`, in addition to the `features` field. You'll need to add such a field to your dataframe before fitting.

Changing the last rows in your code ..

```
// pipeline - with "htf" stage added
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tokenizer, htf, idf, lr))
//Model - with an addition (constant...) label field 
val model = pipeline.fit(dataframe.withColumn("label", lit(1.0)))
```

... will make this finish successfully, but of course the labeling here is just for the example's sake, create the labels as you see fit.